# multiple constructors in C#

Tags: c#, constructor

I have class which needs data, this can be as bytes or as a file path.

At the moment I read the file into a byte array and then setup the class. And in another seperator it sets up the class directly from bytes passed as parameter.

I'd like the first constructor (file path) to call the second (bytes), something like:

```
    public DImage(byte[] filebytes) : this()
    {
        MemoryStream filestream = null;
        BinaryReader binReader = null;
        if (filebytes != null && filebytes.Length > 0)
        {
            using (filestream = new MemoryStream(filebytes))
            {
                if (filestream != null && filestream.Length > 0 && filestream.CanSeek == true)
                {
                    //do stuff
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception(@"Couldn't read file from disk.");
            }
        }
        else
            throw new Exception(@"Couldn't read file from disk.");
    }


    public DImage(string strFileName) : this()
    {
        // make sure the file exists
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName) == true)
        {
            this.strFileName = strFileName;
            byte[] filebytes = null;
            // load the file as an array of bytes
            filebytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(this.strFileName);
            //somehow call the other constructor like
            DImage(filebytes);                         
        }
        else
           throw new Exception(@"Couldn't find file '" + strFileName);

    }
```

So how do I call the first constructor (to save copying and pasting the code), from the second?

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: I appear to have missed that out :) How do i call the first constructor?

Comment: @Jonathan. You can't call chain the constructors that way. I mean, the result of the first to call the 2nd with the resulting byte array. You must extract the logic in methods and just call them manually.

Comment: you can't call another constructor from within the method body, only after the colon, e.g. public DImage(string strFileName) : this() is calling the default (parameterless) constructor.  You would be better off extracting the functionality to a single method and calling that from both constructors, as ken2k suggests

Answer (score 4):

You could create a private method taking a `byte[]` as parameter, say `ProcessImage(byte[] myparam)`, that would be called by both constructors to process your bytes.

Side note: you might want to consider using a `stream` instead of a `byte[]`.

---

Quick example:

```
public DImage(byte[] filebytes) : this()    // Remove if no parameterless constructor
{
    MemoryStream filestream = null;
    BinaryReader binReader = null;
    if (filebytes != null && filebytes.Length > 0)
    {
        using (filestream = new MemoryStream(filebytes))
        {
            this.ProcessStream(filestream);
        }
    }
    else
        throw new Exception(@"Couldn't read file from disk.");
}

public DImage(Stream stream) : this()   // Remove if no parameterless constructor
{
    this.ProcessStream(stream);
}    

public DImage(string strFileName) : this()  // Remove if no parameterless constructor
{
    // make sure the file exists
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName) == true)
    {
        this.strFileName = strFileName;

        // process stream from file
        this.ProcessStream(System.IO.File.Open(strFileName));
    }
    else
       throw new Exception(@"Couldn't find file '" + strFileName);
}

...

private ProcessStream(Stream myStream)
{
    if (filestream != null && filestream.Length > 0 && filestream.CanSeek == true)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    else
        throw new Exception(@"Couldn't read file from disk.");
}
```

Comment: @Jonathan. Essentially because the byte[] is entirely loaded in memory, while the stream isn't. Another reason is that it allows people to call your code with the generic and often used Stream type, without asking them to convert it to byte[] first then back to stream (MemoryStream) later. Ultimately, depending on the context of your project (i.e. will your code be reused by other people than you, is it a lib?) you might want to only expose the constructor that takes a stream as parameter and let code that uses your class do the "file->stream" and "byte[]->stream" stuff.

Comment: I'm adding to someone else's code (with permission), and they provide a byte[]. So I figured it would be better to use byte[]. Would it be better for the code the other person wrote to use a stream then. There have been cases where memory has run out. (But this is not much of a concern as only we will use this program and it is not the main objective, although having said I would like it to work as well as it could)

Answer (score 4):

I would actually suggest exposing two *static* methods:

```
public static DImage FromFile(string filename)
{
    // Load image, then call constructor
}

public static DImage FromData(byte[] data)
{
    // Do anything you need to, then call the constructor
}
```

The exact form of the constructor is up to you, but I'd probably make it private. Using static factory methods leads to clearer code in my experience, and means you can defer calling an *actual* constructor until you're actually ready to do the work. This helps in terms of making fields readonly etc. The big downside is the lack of support for inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine implementing 3 constructors:

1. Accepting a [`System.Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that can be accessed by a [`System.IO.StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)
2. Accepting an array of bytes, wrapping it into an [`System.IO.MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) and calling the first constructor.
3. Accepting an file name, loading it using a [`System.IO.FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) and calling the first constructor.

Here's an example:

```
using System.IO;

// ...

public DImage(Stream Stream)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Stream))
    {
        // Read the image.
    }
}

public DImage(byte[] Bytes) 
    : this(new MemoryStream(Bytes))
{
}

public DImage(string FileName) 
    : this(new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
}
```

This also makes it easier to handle exceptions. The constructor of FileStream will throw an `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`, if the file does not exist, so you can handle it from wherever you are instancing the `DImage`-class:

```
try
{
    var image = new DImage(@"C:\Test.img");
}
catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
{
    // The image could not be found.
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Something else happened.
}
```

This method uses the keyword `this` behind the constructor to delegate special construction cases to the default constructor. It has two advantages:

1. Reduce required code by removing code douples.
2. Increasing reuseability, by defining a default constructor, accepting a `System.Stream`. Clients can either call the constructors to load images from memory chunks or file system entries, or they can implement their own stream to provide custom datasources (like DB BLOBs, NetworkStreams, ...).

Comment: How are the streams when you call another constructor (`this(new MemoryStream(Bytes))` and `this(new FileStream(...))`) disposed?

Comment: They get disposed by the finalizer thread, but it should not be that worse, since the streams aren't supposed to live long (as long as their references are not getting stored inside the instance), so they never leave gen0.